# Does $E(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})\leq \frac{E(f(x))}{E(g(x))}$ hold?

Tags: calculus, probability, functional-analysis, inequality

We current have the relation that $h(x)\leq\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}, f(x)>0, g(x)>0$. Then, can we get that $E(h(x))\leq E(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})$? Furthermore, does $E(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})\leq \frac{E(f(x))}{E(g(x))}$ hold? E is an expectation on variable $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x$ is a discreet random variable, that takes on three values, say $x_1,x_2,x_3$, each with equal likelihood.  Let $f(x_1)=1,f(x_2)=2, f(x_3)=3$, and $g(x_1)=3, g(x_2)=2, g(x_3)=1)$.  Then $E(f(x))=E(g(x))=\frac{1}{3}(1+2+3)=2$. Thus we have
$$\frac{E(f(x))}{E(g(x))}=\frac{2}{2}=1.$$
But $E(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})=\frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{2}+\frac{3}{1})=\frac{13}{9}$. Thus we have $$E(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}>\frac{E(f(x))}{E(g(x))}.$$